# Question Cleanup: Making questions findable for others

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

We've grown a lot in the past 7 years of the site many questions being asked and answered. As of this post over 12,000 questions have been asked. However, as we have grown we have to take care in organizing our content and making it so others can find. As a Q&A site these questions need to be searchable for others.

I find myself looking at questions I know we have answered before in some capacity, which isn't bad in and of itself. The real problem is the inability to find them later. With 12,000 questions this isn't a simple task, but we can together do a few small things to help.

#### Little things everyone can do:

- The title reflects what the core question is about
- Make sure question has relevant tags
- Link related questions in comments

#### Bigger things that take time but will pay off:

- Create new tags that will help organization
- Edit tag excerpts to best reflect their use
- If tag usage is not clear, bring it up to meta for discussion
- Fixing terminology in the question (not the content) so searches will turn up keywords
- Editing excess noise out of the questions
- Suggest tag synonyms and merging
- Bring up possible tags for blacklisting

#### Moderation actions to help:

- Requesting questions that asks too many different questions be split (and flag to put on hold if needed)
- Flag/close questions that are duplicates
- [Add duplicates to the duplicate close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) or flag if you do not have the privilege.

---

If you're unsure of something, please don't hesitate to bring it to the meta so we can reach a community consensus. If you are already editing a question for one of the reasons above please also see if spelling or grammar needs to be fixed in the question and fix it accordingly.

Another thing to note, users under 2k can earn some reputation in this cleanup effort by suggesting the appropriate edits above.

Comment: What do you mean by "Fixing terminology in the question (not the content)"? What is the difference between question and content?

Comment: @anatolyg It's very common for questions to use the wrong term for tagging and in the question. Having the wrong term be used not only makes the question unclear, but harder to find. A good common example is while "beat" is modern slang for "rhythm",  people end up using the beat tag when they should use the rhythm tag and the people reading the question need to understand this also.